# LibreOffice: recursively convert documents in folders and subfolders

Tags: applescript, docx, libreoffice, doc

I have stored many files in the doc format which I can only open with libreoffice on my mac.

The command:

```
 ./soffice --headless --convert-to docx --outdir /home/user ~/Downloads/*.doc
```

does exactly what it should: it converts all the `*.doc` files to libreoffice `*.docx` file.

My problem is that I have folders and subfolders with these files.

Is there any way to search through all the folders from a starting directory and to let "soffice" do its job in each of these folders, storing the new versions (`*.docx`) exactly where the original (`*.doc`) was found.

Unfortunately, I am not well-versed in apple script or in terminal to make this work. Yet there are 8000 doc files in hundreds and hundreds of folders that require the update to docx.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any way to search through all the folders from a starting directory and to let "soffice" do its job in each of these folders, storing the new versions (*.docx) exactly where the original (*.doc) was found.

This can actually be done in **Terminal** using a `find` *command*:

```
find '/path/to/directory' -type f -iname '*.doc' -execdir /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless --convert-to docx '{}' \;
```

In the example *command* above, change `'/path/to/directory'` to the actual *pathname* of the target *directory* that contains the *subdirectories* containing the `.doc` *files*.

What this `find` *command* does, in brief, is it finds all `.doc` *files* within the *hierarchical directory structure* of the `'/path/to/directory'` and  executes the *command* in each *subdirectory* within containing the `.doc` *files* and converts each one in place in its *subdirectory*.

---

**Notes:**

- Always insure you have proper backups before running *commands* in **Terminal** and the *commands* as typed will produce the wanted behavior!
- This *command* assumes no `.docx` *files* already exist of the same *name* as the `.doc` *files* in the *subdirectories*, as it automatically overwrites any existing `.docx` *files* of the same *name* as the `.doc` *files*. As far as I can tell, the `soffice` *command* does not provide an *option* not to overwrite existing files. If this is going to be an issue, then a different solution will be necessary.

Comment: I have been looking for a way to batch edit textfiles from doc to docx for years and the solution is so elegant. I only had to edit the "path/to/directory" and it worked! It took my two days to work through 8000 files, the remaining 8000 were done in ten minutes! You are brillant! (And I guess I shouldn't write this here, but my upvotes aren't counted yet, so forgive me.) Thank you! Merry X-Mas!